# Does Tunisia require a Visa if I don´t disembark while in port?

Tags: visas, tunisia

I am visiting Norway on a 90 day Schengen Visa Single entry. I am booked to go on a cruise from Barcelona to Rome, but it stops in Tunisia for a day and night. If I do not go off the ship, do I need to have a Visa for Tunisia? I am Filipino.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Presumption of visa necessity notwithstanding what's your citizenship?

Comment: I am worried that we might get denied during check in if the visa is really necessary. Since I am on a single entry visa, we thought it's best to not get off the ship so as to not to get a stamp on my passport showing I left the Schengen area.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, customs and immigration formalities are completed in the cruise terminal at the port of departure. For international cruises, it's very likely there would be a border control (and Schengen exit stamp) right at the ferry terminal in Barcelona.

Much like in airports, border guards wait for passengers in little booths and everybody must go through the checkpoint, they don't travel with the ship to stamp passports depending on who leaves the ship or not. So I think you need a two-entry visa in any case, even if you don't plan to disembark in Tunisia or can enter there without a visa.